# Solve $\sum_{i=0}^{\log_3 n-1}i\times 3^i$

Tags: recursion

I want to find the answer for  $$\sum_{i=0}^{\log_3 n-1}i\times 3^i$$

Can you please explain?
I this a geometric series?

Comment: What does "solve" mean here? Also, what did you try? where did you get stuck? Additionally, consider editing the question to clarify it more.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Please use Latex rules to describe your formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider the infinite sum (instead of stopping the sum at $\log_3 n- 1$) you obtain an [arithmetico-geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence).

These series have the general form
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (a + (k-1)\delta)br^{k-1}.
$$

In your particular case $a=0$, $\delta=1$, $b=1$ and $r=3$.
Since a closed-form expression for the generic $m$-th partial sum is known (see the Wikipedia page), you can just substitute the above values in the relevant formula (in your case $m= \lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor$).

Comment: Thank you so much @Steven!!!

Answer (score 1):

A general way to handle similar sums is to start with:

$\begin{align*}
  S_n(z)
    &= \sum_{0 \le k \le n} z^k \\
    &= \frac{1 - z^{n + 1}}{1 - z} \\
 z \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z} S_n(z)
    &= \sum_{0 \le k \le n} k z^k
\end{align*}$

Differentiate, substitute the desired value of $z$ and $n$, and you are set.

Comment: Nice trick!$\phantom{}$

Comment: Thank you so much @vonbrand!!!